# If $M$ is a Hilbert space, can the tensor product $H\otimes H$ be embeded (isometric linear) into $H$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

It is possible that $H\otimes H$ is embeded into $H$?

Comment: I made a mistake $H$ is the Hilbert space